# Ruby open-uri can't open url (m1 mac)

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, open-uri, apple-m1

i start to learn ruby and scraping and i try to open an url with open and i got

`` lib/scrapper.rb:7:in `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_Adams (Errno::ENOENT) from lib/scrapper.rb:7:in `open' from lib/scrapper.rb:7:in `<main>' ``

And this is my code :

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'rubygems'
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

document = open("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_Adams")

puts document
```

After some long hours of google research i don't find any solution 
I test open with this url to : http://www.krosmoz.com/fr/almanax
thanks all

ps i'm on mac m1 don't know if they are compatibility issues

Comment: So the answer is that Ruby thought you wanted to open a file, because you called `Kernel#open` and couldn't find it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The problem is likely that you are using ruby 3.0.0.

Under Ruby 2.7, I receive the following warning:

> warning: calling URI.open via Kernel#open is deprecated, call URI.open directly or use URI#open

And under Ruby 3.0, it has been removed.

So the solution, per the warning:

```rb
document = URI.open("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_Adams").read
```